# Why "Error opening terminal: unknown" after clean CentOS installation?

Tags: linux, centos, terminal, system-installation

I downloaded latest original **CentOS 8 Stream** iso and used it as a disk image to make my VM in VirtualBox (latest version).

So, installation process was usual (previously I used to install CentOS several times without any issues), I chose non-GUI version and add two ticks: to install *debug tools* and to install *sys internal tools*. Installation process was finished without errors.

After my first login, I tried to use `nano` utility, but got `Error opening terminal: unknown.` error. This can be solved by sending `export TERM=linux` string. But the question - why I faced with this issue? I've never seen it before. What can be a crux of this in case of clean CentOS installation from original iso image? It was really unexpected.

P.S. `echo $TERM` shows me `dumb` (after machine reboot)

Answer (score 0):

Lol, I'm dumb.

This is **Termius** issue (I use **Termius** to make a SSH connection to the host).
To solve it, it's enough to add `TERM` variable into **Termius** host options.
Anyway, don't know why it uses `dumb` terminal as default.